# How to edit a line of an HTML page using Google Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I have a website that i use so often for work, there's something in the page that really bothers me and i takes me a lot of time doing it like a normal user, so i found a solution by changing the HTML using chrome devtools, but the problem is that the HTML is very large and it takes a lot of time changing only one line manually.

Here is a part of the code :

```
<tr id="appl_tr" height="30">
    <td valign="middle" class="styleBlack" width="34%" style="padding-left:10px;">
     Birthdate : <span style="color:#F00">*</span> 
    </td>
    <td width="66%" align="left" valign="middle">
         <input type="text" name="dateOfBirth" class="form-control-input" id="dateOfBirth" value="" readonly="" >
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want only using chrome console, to remove only that **readonly=""** thing in the sixth line, so it will be like this :

```
<input type="text" name="dateOfBirth" class="form-control-input" id="dateOfBirth" value="" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use javascript in console?

`document.querySelector('#dateOfBirth').removeAttribute('readonly')`